# Links to election nomination pages from notifications don't have the right #anchor

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, nominations

I recently received a notification that someone posted a comment on my election nomination post. That notification linked me to this URL: https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-34503

However, the anchor `#post-34503` doesn't link you anywhere in particular. It just leaves you at the top of the page. The actual anchor for my post is `#post-23961`.

"34503" appears to be the ID of the comment in question - https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/1#comment-34503 does take me to the right place.

Comment: I saw this earlier and thought, "OK, cool, whatever." Then it happened to me….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed as of build 2862. I'm using the comment anchor rather than the nomination post anchor.